# how to index each page of a pdfdocument as a seperate Solr document

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm trying to retrieve page numbers from where a search result was found in solr. I have found that indexing each page as a seperate solr document would work. But I can't seem to find a way to index a single page from a pdf file.

Has anyone found a way to index a single page of a document with solr?

Comment: See here: http://find.searchhub.org/document/2d5774edaf7df967#584a8c3c378ba4c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use any library for example [pdfbox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) in order to extract text from each page separately and submit distinct documents to Solr